# display the values as per the priority in reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript

I have two array of Objects,array1 and array2. I can only show three values from both the arrays but priority is given to the array1. Requirement is, if array1 contains 3 elements, then show all the three elements. If array1 contain 2 elements then show 2 elements from array1 and 1 element from array2. If array1 contain contains 1 elements, then show rest 2 elements from array2. I am not sure how to put this logic in my react code.
Right now, I am simply printing all the values. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
{arrayOne.map((data) => (
                      <ListOfValues
                        data={product.details}
                      ></ListOfValues>
                  ))}

 {arrayTwo.map((data) => (
                      <ListOfValues
                        data={product.details}
                      ></ListOfValues>
                  ))}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i tried adding .slice(0,1) . But it wont show the values dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
{arrayOne.concat(arrayTwo).slice(0, 3).map((data) => (
                      <ListOfValues
                        data={product.details}
                      ></ListOfValues>
                  ))}
```

Comment: yes and if array2 is not an array, but the object of type : {sample1: "asd", sample2: "sad"}, then how to concat them

Comment: both these arrays holds the object, but those object type are different. So when I am using concat , it shows error, since types are different